# Where can I find the default printing test page?

Tags: printing

where can i find the default test page in ubuntu ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These 2 are on our system:

```
/usr/share/system-config-printer/testpage-a4.ps
/usr/share/system-config-printer/testpage-letter.ps
```

Oh and looks like if you delete these the CUPS test page is used.

Comment: In more recent Ubuntu, the location seems to have changed. See @konrad ’s answer

Comment: I agree with @FrédéricGrosshans

Answer (score 16):

For Ubuntu 12.04 the testpage is in the following location:

```
/usr/share/cups/data/default-testpage.pdf
```

Comment: Also true for Ubuntu 14.04. The location seems to have changed after Rinzwind's answer.

Comment: same for RHEL/CentOS 7

Comment: **This path is valid** in Kubuntu 22.04. I, successfully, changed the `default-testpage.pdf` to new one.